# How can I become a contributor developer for the Betaflight project?

Tags: betaflight

I am a mobile developer for the Android platform and recently found I highly growing passion for self-built drones.

I have also noticed the community around this hobby is very collaborative and it would be extremely helpful to know a viable way of becoming a contributor to the Betaflight project to start doing my part for the community.

Comment: This question is specific to BetaFlight's governance and should be directed to them, either via email or on their forums.

Answer (score 3):

Normally the best way is to start by forking the betaflight or configurator repository and work on some issues in their respective GitHub issue trackers and submit pull requests. Given that you are an Android developer, I assume you are familiar with UI development so I'm sure they would appreciate some feedback on the configurator UX.